# Create properties for Static UITableViewCell Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I decided today that using static tableViews would suit my app better than dynamic ones.

Each cell has a label, and a `UITextField`

I subclassed one of the static cells and then tried to create `IBOutlets` for the label and textField... only it wouldn't work. Zero `IBOutlet` functionality when it comes static cells apparently and their subclass

I can however drag in `IBOutlets` to the `UITableViewController` these cells are apart of

So, essentially I would have a `UITableViewController` with outlets for each cell, each cells textField, each cells label, and potentially any other properties I want to add to the cell

I didn't want that much annoying code so I tried using dynamics

I was able to create `IBOutlets` for each object the way you can normally expect

I again decided against dynamics `UITableViewCells`, and switched back to static...

ONLY the static cells now have `IBOutlets` connected to them (they didn't disappear or throw errors when i returned to static `UITableView`)

I can access the cells properties by using cell.textField which is a lot better than a billion `IBOutlets` for each object on the cell

My question is... Why can't I create `IBOutlets` on the subclass of Static TableViewCells

Is the way I did it the only way, or is there a better way? I would hate to keep switching back and forth, but it allows me to get rid of dozens of lines of code I'll do it

Comment: did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Only thing that worked was switching to dynamic, setting up the properties, then switching back to static

Answer (score 0):

When you create `IBOulet` for a `UITableViewCell` and you try to connect them on your StoryBoard, go to the left bar (where the objects of your view controller are) and press Ctrl + Click over your custom cell. Then the `IBOutlet` object will appear in a popup and you will be able to link them.